# Conflicting constructor at runtime in generic class

Tags: java, generics

Was working on something simple with a generic class that has two constructor

```
public class GenericObject<M> {

    private String string;
    private M generic;

    public GenericObject(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    public GenericObject(M generic) {
        this.generic= generic;
        this.string = "default";
   }

}
```

then at one point i needed a `GenericObject<String>`

```
GenericObject<String> obj = new GenericObject<>("randomString");
```

and i found out later on when debugging that the String constructor was being used instead of the expected generic one.

I can change however i want this class so it's not a problem to fix, but i was wondering if there's a way to hint which constructor to use in this situation at runtime

Comment: The `String` constructor is used because it's more precise than the `Object` constructor used for generic invocation. I'd say you've designed the class badly in this case.

Comment: I've seen this question before at least a few times.  I think the JLS says in cases of uncertainty about which method to call, the more specific version gets called.  In this case, `String` is more specific than the generic version, so the former gets called.

Comment: i see... thx for the quick answer! going to change design right away

Comment: This is a great example from the pedagogical point of view  (for explaining generics, type erasure and static binding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see the byte code: [image]

Because of the type erasure the 2nd constructors becomes `public GenericObject(Object generic)` and as users Kayaman and Tim Biegeleisen said, the `String` is more specific then `Object`, thus the first constructor gets called.

Comment: just to complete - here some examples from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html